# Why is the Extract function giving wrong array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array, extract

> I have a 2D array, and I want to return only the male students in a new array. I want to use the **extract function** specifically. However, the condition is correct, but the extract function is giving a wrong output.

```
# creating an a numpy array with the names of students along with their corresponding biological sex
students=np.array([["alexis", "female"],["alex", "male"], ["david", "non-binary"], ["samar", "male"], ["anweshan","male"]])

# creating a condition to check if a student is a male or not

con = students[0: , 1] == "male"

#creating a new array with only the male students
male_students = np.extract(con, students)
print(male_students)
```

This gives a wrong output, which is as follows

> ['female' 'male' 'david']

However, writing the code in a different manner gives the correct output. The code is as follows:

```
# creating an a numpy array with the names of students along with their corresponding biological sex
students=np.array([["alexis", "female"],["alex", "male"], ["david", "non-binary"], ["samar", "male"], ["anweshan","male"]])

# creating a condition to check if a student is a male or not

con1 = students[0: , 1] == "male"
print(con1)
print(students[con1])
```

It gives the following output

> [['alex' 'male']
> ['samar' 'male']
> ['anweshan' 'male']]

I want to use the extract function, so can you please tell where I'm making a mistake?

Answer (score 1):

Your con array is not of the same shape.

```
con = students[: , 1] == "male"

con_same_shape = np.empty((5,2))

con_same_shape[:,0] = con
con_same_shape[:,1] = con

#creating a new array with only the male students
male_students = np.extract(con_same_shape, students)

print(male_students)
```

will return:

```
['alex' 'male' 'samar' 'male' 'anweshan' 'male']
```

Comment: you could reshape the output like this:

print(male_students.reshape(((int)(len(male_students)/2),2)))